# Comparing 2 strings in python "wordwise" and extracting their difference

Tags: python, algorithm, difflib

i just want to compare 2 strings and extract their difference wordwise. Already i've seen about what difflib can do.

example:

```py
a = "Allows you to compare data with unknown or inconsistent encoding All inputs except n must be bytes objects not str Works by losslessy"
b = "Allows you to ata with unknown or inconsistent check encothing All inputs except n musing lol be bytes objects not str orks by lossless"

diff = enumerate(d.ndiff(a,b))
for i,s in diff:
    if s[0] in ('+','-'):
        print(i,s)
```

### Problem 1:

The above code compares the strings,one glaring error that pops up here is, sometimes a space pops up as shown below in the 21st index (and other areas of the complete output snippet), yeah i think i can ignore this by changin the if statement to ignore spaces, but does that supplement the bottom problem?

(a short portion of the output snippet)

```
19 - r
20 - e
21 -  
22 - d
56 + c
```

### Problem 2, word-wise comparison:

Taking the above string example:

- the 3rd word is missing in `a` so it should skip it
- the 4th word has a missing letter and hence it should indicate that like ("data","ata","- d")
- the 9th word is an extra in `b` it should skip that as well
- the 10th word(encoding) has a mistake and hence it should indicate as ("encoding","encothing","+ t")

so on and so forth. any guidelines or suggestions?

Comment: For problem 2, define whether a word should be skipped entirely (one function), and if not, compare each letter `for l1, l2 in itertools.zip_longest(word1, word2)` to define which one is missing or extra and add it with + or - to a list of letters (another function). Words are taken from `word1, word2 in itertools.zip_longest(a, b)` and you need to define the missing value as `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Just transform your strings into lists and use difflib library. More details in https://stackabuse.com/comparing-strings-using-python/

```
import difflib
 
a = ["Allows you to compare data with unknown or inconsistent encoding All inputs except n must be bytes objects not str Works by losslessy"]
b = ["Allows you to ata with unknown or inconsistent check encothing All inputs except n musing lol be bytes objects not str orks by lossless"]


difference = difflib.Differ()

#Calculates the difference
diff = difference.compare(a,b)
 
print ('\n'.join(diff))
```